# RN - Prop value syntax within Image Require

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am relatively new to RN and stuck with a syntax issue..

I need to use a prop value to populate the source of an image.  Can someone please help me with the syntax required to do this?

```
<Image style={AppStyles.buttonRectIcon} source={require('{this.props.buttonIcon})'} />
```

Above produces an error 'invalid keyword 'this' however the same syntax works fine within a string below -

```
<Text style={AppStyles.buttonRectText}>{this.props.buttonTxt}</Text>
```

The prop value is passed from the parent component via:

```
  <ButtonRect buttonTxt='Login' buttonIcon={require("../button.png")} buttonIcon='../images/icons/ico-login.png' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument for require cannot be a variable. It has to be static.
For e.g `require("../sample.png")`

If you meant to pass a local image, you could send as follows:

```
<ButtonRect buttonTxt='Login' buttonIcon={require('../images/icons/ico-login.png')} />
```

and then in your child component

```
<Image 
style={AppStyles.buttonRectIcon} 
source={this.props.buttonIcon} />
```

If it is a remote url you could write like

```
<Image 
style={AppStyles.buttonRectIcon} 
source={{uri: this.props.buttonIcon}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<Image 
style={AppStyles.buttonRectIcon} 
source={{uri: this.props.buttonIcon}} />
```

Comment: thanks @sathish - no luck - wonder if its a problem at the call - ie - <ButtonRect buttonTxt='Login' buttonIcon='../images/icons/ico-login.png' />